# Playing while publishing in wowza server

Tags: stream, rtmp, wowza

I am using the Wowza media server to publish a stream via RTMP.
Now I would like to go further.

I want to play the video while I'm publishing it, without starting playing again.

How can I perform this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to outline what technologies are you using.
It is not a big deal to create flash app that will publish and play simultaneously.
If it is related to mobile applications then it is harder to accomplish that goal.

Comment: I'm working on client-server app which allows user to stream something using your Android phone on a central server whose runs WMS. 
Now, I'm able to publish the stream but, how can I play it while the Android phone is sending it up?

Comment: again, if you developed code to publish the stream then you know all that RTMP/RTSP internal things, so i cannot understand why can't you play some stream from Wowza... should be much easier than publishing.

Comment: Not able to play the stream at the same time. I need to reload the web page where the player is embedded in to watch the scenes the client uploaded. It's like WOWZA can play a stream which is complete and it's not able to play a stream which is contisuoly updated.